# Multiple PUT methods in Jersey Rest Service

Tags: java, rest, http, methods, jersey

I was wondering if it is possible to have two `PUT` methods in one `resource` which take a differing number of arguments via a `Form`.

Eg:

```
    @PUT
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
     public Response updateOrderStatus(
        @FormParam("status") String status
        ){
               ....
        }

    @PUT
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public Response updateOrder(
        @FormParam("coffeeType") String type,           
        @FormParam("addition") String addition,
        @FormParam("cost") String cost
        ){
               ....
         }
```

I tried replicating the functions but only changing the function names and it compiled without error. Is this acceptable and if so, is it considered good/bad practice?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will work because methods are matched on the basis of reference URL and HTTP method. As both the method, share the same reference URL and same HTTP method, at runtime jersey should throw an error for ambiguous mapping.